# Splitting 2 Sequences into three based on elements present/not present

Tags: scala

I need to match 2 separate visitor arrivals given 2 arrival sequences which are defined via a case class.

I also define a contains function which compares an element against another element in a sequence based on start and end time which returns a boolean.

I need to split the 2 sequences in a way that produces 3 sequences such as:

1. Whatever is covered in sequence b and a,
2. Whatever that is not covered in sequence b and a,
3. Whatever is left over in b

I have part of a solution via `partition` function:

```
def contains(as: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], bs: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]): (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]) = {
bs match {
  case Seq() => (Nil, as)
  case bs => as.partition(a => bs.exists(b => b.contains(a)))
}
```

}

This produces points 1 and 2 above

```
 contains(a,b)
res2: (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]) = 
(List(websiteVisitsWindow(1,1,2)),List(websiteVisitsWindow(0,0,1), 
websiteVisitsWindow(3,3,11)))

case class websiteVisitsWindow(start: Int, end: Int, visitors: Int) {
 def contains(other: websiteVisitsWindow): Boolean = other.start >= this.start && other.end <= this.end
 }


val a = Seq(websiteVisitsWindow(start = 0, end = 0, visitors = 1), websiteVisitsWindow(start = 1, end = 1, visitors = 2), websiteVisitsWindow(start = 3, end = 3, visitors = 11))

val b = Seq(websiteVisitsWindow(start = 1, end = 1, visitors = 2), websiteVisitsWindow(start = 4, end = 4, visitors = 60))
```

The result that I need is:

```
(List(websiteVisitsWindow(1,1,2)),List(websiteVisitsWindow(0,0,1), 
websiteVisitsWindow(3,3,11)), List(websiteVisitsWindow(4,4,60))
```

I have a function definition already as:

```
def intersectionAndLeftOver(as: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], bs: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]): (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow])
```

I was asked I can do this as a recursion, at the moment I am just trying to get the sequences result without recursion and then go from there.

I tried the following:

```
def intersectionAndLeftOver(as: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], bs: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]): (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]) = {
(as, bs) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => (Nil, Nil, Nil)
  case (_, Nil) => (Nil, as, Nil)
  case (Nil, _) => (Nil, bs, Nil)

  case (as, bs) =>
    (as.partition(a => bs.exists(b => b.contains(a))), as.filter(a => !(bs.exists(b => b.contains(a)) )))

}
}
```

But of course the result returns (partition, Seq) which is not (Seq, Seq, Seq) return type.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that "works" for now:

```
def intersectionAndLeftOver(as: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], bs: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]): (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]) = {
(as, bs) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => (Nil, Nil, Nil)
  case (_, Nil) => (Nil, as, Nil)
  case (Nil, _) => (Nil, bs, Nil)

  case (as, bs) =>
    (as.intersect(bs), as.diff(bs), bs.diff(as))

}
}
```

It is not as optimised as doing going the recursive way and I can see when this will break (for example if 1 sequence only has start/end but all visitor values set to 0 while the other sequence has all the information correctly set) this will need to be addressed later on